# Find Location Address from latitude and longitude

Tags: java, geocoding

I want to find the city and country from latitude and longitude in Java. I did this in JavaScript and it returns the correct location but I want to do this in Java. How can I do this?

Comment: you can by using [open map](http://openmap.bbn.com/) or [simpleLatLng](http://code.google.com/p/simplelatlng/).

Comment: Not sure what's so hard to understand about this question.  It's a good one. Not really opinion-based, either.